# Bash: how to certain lines but exclude certain lines in between?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, pcre, pcregrep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
a: 0
a: 0
a: 0
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1
d: 1
e: 1
f: 1
a: 2
b: 2
c: 2
d: 2
e: 2
f: 2
a: 3
b: 3
c: 3
d: 3
e: 3
f: 3
c: 4
c: 4
c: 4
```

I want to capture and output all of the `a` and `c` lines of the form `<a line><anything other than an a or c line><c line>` so the output would look like:

```
a: 1
c: 1

a: 2
c: 2

a: 3
c: 3
```

Note that neither the `a: 0` lines at the beginning nor the `c: 4` lines at the end are captured because they don't follow the pattern I mentioned. Note also that the `b` lines between the `a` and `c` lines are removed.

I've been trying to do this with lookarounds usings Bash's pcregrep, but haven't found a solution yet. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: why over-complicating with `pcre` , have you tried `grep -E '^[ac]'` ?

Comment: What did you try? What does it have to do with `bash`? Where did you find that `bash` provides `pcregrep`? Post your attempts made so far

Comment: Why are there blanks between two lines each in the output?

Comment: @PS. I edited my original post. I'd left out some info before. You're right that the regex you suggested solves what I'd originally written, so I upvoted.

Comment: @Inian I updated my original post, I had left some info out. Re bash, I'm writing pcregrep commands in the bash shell on OS X (terminal). An example of what I've tried so far is pcregrep -M '^a(?=(^b))^c' , where I'm trying to match a line that starts with 'a' that has a 'b' line ahead of it, and a 'c' line, and to include the 'a' and 'c' lines only.

Comment: You probably want an awk solution, multi-line with grep gets messy fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using awk

Try:

```
$ awk -F: '$1=="a"{aline=$0} $1=="c"{if(aline)print aline ORS $0 ORS; aline=""}' file
a: 1
c: 1

a: 2
c: 2

a: 3
c: 3
```

#### How it works

By default, awk reads in one line at a time.

- `-F:`

  This tells awk to use `:` as the field separator.
- `$1=="a"{aline=$0}`

  Everytime an `a` line is observed, save the line in variable `aline`.
- `$1=="c"{if(aline)print aline ORS $0 ORS; aline=""}`

  Every time a `c` line is observed, check to see if we have a nonempty `aline`.  If so, print `aline` and the current line, separated by newline characters.  Also, set `aline` back to an empty string.

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their commands spread over several lines:

```
awk -F: '
    $1=="a"{
        aline=$0
    }

   $1=="c"{
        if(aline)
            print aline ORS $0 ORS
        aline=""
    }' file
```

## Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/^a/h; /^c/{x;/^a/{p;x;s/$/\n/;p};h}' file
a: 1
c: 1

a: 2
c: 2

a: 3
c: 3
```

#### How it works

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/^a/h`

  Any time we have a line that starts with `a`, we save it to the hold space.
- `/^c/{ x; /^a/{ p; x; s/$/\n/; p}; h}`

  Any time we have a line that starts with `c`, we:

  - We swap (`x`) the pattern space with the hold space.
  - If the new pattern space starts with `a`, then we print (`p`) it, and swap (`x`) again, add a new line to the end of the new pattern space (`s/$/\n/`) and print (`p`) it.
  - Lastly we save the current pattern space (which starts with a `c`) to the hold space.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used awk before, but I'll try using this.